# User profile: Question answered view count

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

I have realized that from a user profile you don't get to see the question view count for your answers.

Wouldn't it be nice to know how many people may have read your answers?

Comment: Yes, you do. The information is all still available. If you click on the answer, you can check the view counter on the question page.

Comment: I know that. Why do questions have the counter visible in the user profile then? I think it would be useful to have the same feature for answers, instead of having to click each one. You can sort answers by `views` but you can't see the number of them.

Comment: Presumably to conserve space. I like to be able to see more of my answers at a time than I care about seeing how many people have viewed them.

Comment: Question view count doesn't take much space. Anyway, it was only a feature I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question view count includes all views of the question.  Your answer view count is less than the question because you would be posting it at some point after the question was originally posted.  It might even be far less if your answer is posted to an old question.

I am not sure, but my guess that view counts from the time that you post and answer only are not calculated or stored.  Therefore it would not be something that could be displayed in your profile.  Furthermore, even if it was calculated, it is fairly useless because people click on a question, but you have no idea if they scroll down and view your answer.  Especially if your answer is not on the top.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think it would give the user a hint (knowing that the number would reflect the question counter not the answer), but it wouldn't be accurate.